# Ensemble learning, multiple classifier system

Tags: c#, matlab, machine-learning, bayesian, ensemble-learning

I am trying to use a MCS (Multi classifier system) to do some better work on limited data i.e become more accurate.

I am using K-means clustering at the moment but may choose to go with FCM (Fuzzy c-means) with that the data is clustered into groups (clusters) the data could represent anything, colours for example. I first cluster the data after pre-processing and normalization and get some distinct clusters with a lot in between. I then go on to use the clusters as the data for a Bayes classifier, each cluster represents a distinct colour and the Bayes classifier is trained and the data from the clusters is then put through separate Bayes classifiers. Each Bayes classifier is trained only in one colour. If we take the colour spectrum 3 - 10 as being blue 13 - 20 as being red and the spectrum in between 0 - 3 being white up to 1.5 then turning blue gradually through 1.5 - 3 and same for blue to red.

What I would like to know is how or what kind of aggregation method (if that is what you would use) could be applied so that the Bayes classifier can become stronger, and how does it work? Does the aggregation method already know the answer or would it be human interaction that corrects the outputs and then those answers go back into the Bayes training data?  Or a combination of both? Looking at Bootstrap aggregating it involves having each model in the ensemble vote with equal weight so not quite sure in this particular instance I would use bagging as my aggregation method? Boosting however involves incrementally building an ensemble by training each new model instance to emphasize the training instances that previous models mis-classified, not sure if this would be a better alternative to bagging as im unsure how it incrementally builds upon new instances? And the last one would be Bayesian model averaging which is an ensemble technique that seeks to approximate the Bayes Optimal Classifier by sampling hypotheses from the hypothesis space, and combining them using Bayes' law, however completely unsure how you would sample hypotheses from search space?

I know that usualy you would use a competitive approach to bounce between the two classification algorithms one says yes one says maybe a weighting could be applied and if its correct you get the best of both classifiers but for keep sake I dont want a competitive approach.

Another question is using these two methods together in such a way would it be beneficial, i know the example i provided is very primitive and may not apply in that example but can it be beneficial in more complex data.

Comment: I think you'd get better answers at the dsp board

Comment: Hi sorry what is the dsp board, signal processing?

Comment: Yep http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or at [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: My question is on both no response tho.

Comment: Can you please describe the input and output of the classifiers in more detail, and state the goal of your optimization? As far as I can understand from the text, there are several Bayesian classifiers running on the data; however, I'm unclear as to what is the ultimate use of the outputs (are there discreet classes? continous real number?), and what is the purpose of using ensemble method in this context.

Comment: I would recommend you to post the links to the other posts (and in the other posts include the link here) Otherwise people won't know whether they will make an effort for a problem that may have already been solved elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I have some issues about the method you are following:

1. K-means puts in each cluster the points that are the most near to it. And then you train a classifier using the output data. I think that the classifier may outperform the clustering implicit classification, but only by taking into account the number of samples in each cluster. For example, if your training data after clustering you have typeA(60%), typeB(20%), typeC(20%); your classifier will prefer to take ambiguous samples to typeA, to obtain less classification error.
2. K-means depends on what "coordinates"/"features" you take from the objects. If you use features where the objects of different types are mixed, the K-means performance will decrease. Deleting these kind of features from the feature vector may improve your results.
3. Your "feature"/"coordinates" that represent the objects that you want to classify may be measured in different units. This fact can affect your clustering algorithm since you are implicitly setting a unit conversion between them through the clustering error function. The final set of clusters is selected with multiple clustering trials (that were obtained upon different cluster initializations), using an error function. Thus, an implicit comparison is made upon the different coordinates of your feature vector (potentially introducing the implicit conversion factor).

Taking into account these three points, you will probably increase the overall performance of your algorithm by adding preprocessing stages. For example in object recognition for computer vision applications, most of the information taken from the images comes only from borders in the image. All the color information and part of the texture information are not used. The borders are substracted from the image processing the image to obtain the Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG) descriptors. This descriptor gives back "features"/"coordinates" that separate better the objects, thus, increasing classification (object recognition) performance. Theoretically descriptors throw information contained in the image. However, they present two main advantages (a) the classifier will deal with lower dimensionality data and (b) descriptors calculated from test data can be more easily matched with training data.

In your case, I suggest that you try to improve your accuracy taking a similar approach:

1. Give richer features to your clustering algorithm
2. Take advantage of prior knowledge in the field to decide what features you should add and delete from your feature vector
3. Always consider the possibility of obtaining labeled data, so that supervised learning algorithms can be applied

I hope this helps...